After hardware failure and repair, I am booting straight to grub. Boot-Repair disk gives an error
I need some help getting my server to boot again. I run an older server with ESXi 6.7 with several VMs running off of it in my home lab. The cache card went bad crashing the server and causing several of my Ubuntu boxes to no longer boot. I tried using the boot-repair disk and I am getting:
"Please enable a repository containing the [grub2] packages in the software sources of Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv). Then try again."
I would assume the official repositories would have it, but I guess I am missing something here. The pastebin from the Boot-Repair disk is linked below.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/CRxjd5N2Md/

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sde.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       xfs
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sde1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       xfs
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/sde1: mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: SVGA II Adapter from VMware
Live-session OS is Linuxmint 64-bit (Linux Mint 21.2, victoria, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 6.00(4.6) from Phoenix Technologies LTD
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdc : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdd : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sde : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdc1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdd1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sde1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdb1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, xfs
sdc1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdd1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sde1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, xfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-bad-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sdb1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdc1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdc
sdd1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdd
sde1    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sde

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 250 GiB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Disk identifier: 2F1FA46F-4C22-42A0-AAF3-00A829A21284
       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sda1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
sda2     4096   2101247   2097152    1G Linux filesystem
sda3  2101248 524287933 522186686  249G Linux filesystem
Disk sdc: 2.5 TiB, 2748779069440 bytes, 5368709120 sectors
Disk identifier: C9D2A50B-4FCE-432A-9F83-CD781AC2D1B5
     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdc1   2048 5368707071 5368705024  2.5T Linux filesystem
Disk sdd: 750 GiB, 805306368000 bytes, 1572864000 sectors
Disk identifier: 81ADCCF6-CF8A-4E5B-B08F-6DC0846F98A2
     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdd1   2048 1572861951 1572859904  750G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 1.5 TiB, 1649267441664 bytes, 3221225472 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xf416169f
     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1        2048 3221225471 3221223424  1.5T 83 Linux
Disk sde: 128 GiB, 137438953472 bytes, 268435456 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x97c0363f
     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
sde1        2048 268435455 268433408  128G 83 Linux
Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 249 GiB, 267357519872 bytes, 522182656 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:268GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:VMware Virtual disk:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:1076MB:1074MB:ext4::;
3:1076MB:268GB:267GB:::;
sdb:1649GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:VMware Virtual disk:;
1:1049kB:1649GB:1649GB:xfs::;
sdc:2749GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:VMware Virtual disk:;
1:1049kB:2749GB:2749GB:ext4:Linux filesystem:;
sdd:805GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:VMware Virtual disk:;
1:1049kB:805GB:805GB:ext4::;
sde:137GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:VMware Virtual disk:;
1:1049kB:137GB:137GB:xfs::;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv:267GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:267GB:267GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                      FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                  PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                      
├─sda1                                                                       2727e1e2-0eeb-426c-bc0a-78494699b5ef                        
├─sda2                    ext4        7ffb3930-f16d-42e1-9d0c-3b2855f556c2   c66350ed-e837-42ce-b63f-c2a8cecf1bed                        
└─sda3                    LVM2_member 23l449-LFXa-8yMH-gYS1-ehhh-5k21-0NgmE3 8d0a3dd6-fc96-4c8a-861f-58189d48697c                        
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        9bec9700-d34e-49d7-9d1b-d68db68eff6b                                                               
sdb                                                                                                                                      
└─sdb1                    xfs         591c480d-a6af-46e1-8ebb-8a6dc90bf4d6   f416169f-01                                                 
sdc                                                                                                                                      
└─sdc1                    ext4        6e9bd814-bc46-49ac-bbdc-a8fc03ae3e4b   2c981c46-c34f-4e62-966f-341f304e05da                        Linux filesystem
sdd                                                                                                                                      
└─sdd1                    ext4        213a0d01-0f57-4829-91ac-6c972e6f309c   57dc6d39-a9d3-47b9-ac5f-693969fb2635                        
sde                                                                                                                                      
└─sde1                    xfs         d01a5c9b-e91b-42b1-879e-b7fbc3e1ce39   97c0363f-01                                                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                   Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  82.6G  62% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
/dev/sda2                           696M  22% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                         160.3G  90% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdc1                         151.7G  89% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1
/dev/sdd1                          86.6G  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdd1

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda2                         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                         xfs             rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota
/dev/sdc1                         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdd1                         ext4            rw,relatime

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

======================== sda2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================


==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.132843018 = 0.142639104    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0.222984314 = 0.239427584    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0.819396973 = 0.879820800    vmlinuz                                        1
   0.475646973 = 0.510722048    vmlinuz-5.4.0-189-generic                      1
   0.819396973 = 0.879820800    vmlinuz-5.4.0-193-generic                      1
   0.475646973 = 0.510722048    vmlinuz.old                                    1
   0.997791290 = 1.071370240    initrd.img                                     4
   0.607158661 = 0.651931648    initrd.img-5.4.0-189-generic                   2
   0.997791290 = 1.071370240    initrd.img-5.4.0-193-generic                   4
   0.607158661 = 0.651931648    initrd.img.old                                 2

================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no


==================== blkid (filtered) before lvm activation ====================

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UUID="9bec9700-d34e-49d7-9d1b-d68db68eff6b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda2: UUID="7ffb3930-f16d-42e1-9d0c-3b2855f556c2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c66350ed-e837-42ce-b63f-c2a8cecf1bed"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="591c480d-a6af-46e1-8ebb-8a6dc90bf4d6" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="f416169f-01"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="6e9bd814-bc46-49ac-bbdc-a8fc03ae3e4b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="2c981c46-c34f-4e62-966f-341f304e05da"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="213a0d01-0f57-4829-91ac-6c972e6f309c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="57dc6d39-a9d3-47b9-ac5f-693969fb2635"
/dev/sde1: UUID="d01a5c9b-e91b-42b1-879e-b7fbc3e1ce39" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="97c0363f-01"
/dev/sr0: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2023-12-23-05-05-55-00" LABEL="Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="14eb2669" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda3: UUID="23l449-LFXa-8yMH-gYS1-ehhh-5k21-0NgmE3" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="8d0a3dd6-fc96-4c8a-861f-58189d48697c"
/dev/sda1: PARTUUID="2727e1e2-0eeb-426c-bc0a-78494699b5ef"


================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<249.00 GiB] inherit
blkid -g



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to enable-lvm) and reinstall the grub2 of
mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:  sda2/boot
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (VMware Virtual disk) disk!

sprunge.us ko ()


use the boot-repair  package installed in  the live session instead.

I tried running it without it updating and I got the same message. I am running the version installed on the ISO image.

Have you considered that the repair is not possible the damage is great?

I have. I also know there is a ton about Linux I do not know so I wanted to make sure I was not missing anything before I go through with decomming these VMs and starting over.

Install grub directly from the live session:
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda 

When you can boot to the system apply:
sudo update-grub


Thanks. I will give this a try. I appreciate the help!

Thanks, this helped me get back to a state where I could boot it but there is too much corruption. I appreciate the help.
